# hibernate select data according to user input where user input is alongside few comma separated data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

LeaveType Table

```
leave_name       emp_gender   employment_type       max_allowed_leave
Sick Leave       male,female  permanent,contractual    10
Maternity Leave  female       permanent                240
Annual Leave     male,female  permanent                15
Paternity Leave  male         permanent                30
```

I want to create a drop down list according to employment_type and gender.If Employee is female and permanent then value of the drop down would be Sick Leave,Maternity and Annual as well as only Sick Leave would be shown form employee who is a contractual male and female employee.How to do so in hibernate.N.B: data in emp_gender and  employment_type fields are separated using comma.
 I tried little like following:

```
    Query query = session.createQuery("from LeaveTable where empGender = :empGender and employmentType =:employmentType ");
query.setParameter("empGender ", currentUser.getGender());
query.setParameter("employmentType ", currentUser.getemploymentType ());
List list = query.list();
```

For Female and permanent leave type will be: 1.Sick 2.Maternity 3.Annual.Need suggestions to fix the problem in hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You are not following database normalization. You need to segregate your data into multiple tables for efficient and reliable querying. For the above table you need to use 'LIKE' Operator else you would end up getting nothing.

Comment: I an not allowed to use normalization.I want to use comma separetor for empgender field in java.

Comment: Then you need use LIKE operator